# How to multiply sql values

Tags: android, sql, textview, multiplication

I made SQL database and populated it with values. In TextView I need to show multiply result of specific rows. 
I made SQL statement and I hope that is correct.

```
public List<Food> multiplyFat(){
    String totalFat = "SELECT " +FoodEntry.COLUMN_FAT_TOTAL + " FROM " + FoodEntry.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ( "
            +FoodEntry.COLUMN_FAT_TOTAL + " * " + FoodEntry.COLUMN_GRAM + " ) > 0";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    List<Food> storeTotalFat = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(totalFat, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            double fat = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(0));
            storeTotalFat.add(new Food(fat));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return storeTotalFat;
}
```

To be more clear I need to multiply values from row COLUMN_FAT_TOTAL with row COLUMN_GRAM and display result into the TextView. Or should I put these SQL statement:

```
String totalFat = "SELECT " +FoodEntry.COLUMN_FAT_TOTAL + " * " +FoodEntry.COLUMN_GRAM + " FROM " +FoodEntry.TABLE_NAME;
```

That is simplier way but I am not sure that it is correct way.

Anyhow I need to display this `multiplyFat()` function (result) into TextView. Any help or advice would be really helpfull.

Comment: You'll probably want to use an ***`alias`*** for the product column, unless you don't wat to get a single column from your query.

Comment: You need to mulitply and show individual multiplications as each row in text field or you need sum of all multiplications

Comment: Added my answer for individual multiplications and not sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public List multiplyFat(){

```
String totalFat = "SELECT " +FoodEntry.COLUMN_FAT_TOTAL + " FROM " + FoodEntry.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ( "
        +FoodEntry.COLUMN_FAT_TOTAL + " * " + FoodEntry.COLUMN_GRAM + " ) > 0";
```

The above works perfectly in MySQL, I just tried it.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); --> db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```

Since you are not changing anything in the SQLite database you want a '.getReadableDatbase();' not '.getWritableDatabase();'

```
List<Food> storeTotalFat = new ArrayList<>();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(totalFat, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
  while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    do {
        double fat = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(0));
        storeTotalFat.add(new Food(fat));
    } cursor.moveToNext();
  }
cursor.close();
return storeTotalFat;
}
```

See how I first moved to the first index, then I ask it to continue in a while loop until it has reached the final element in the SQL results. Your way was not actually incrementing the cursor, it would have only been able to add the first result to the storeTotalFat ArrayList.

-------- part 2 ---------

Now let's pretend we are back in the activity, woo!
Let's say there is a class variable reference to the database helper and add a new ArrayList to house the results from the query result we just gained.

```
DBHelper myDBhelper = DBHelper.getInstance(MainActivity.this) 
ArrayList<String> sqlResultArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you want a Recyclerview you make a separate RviewAdapter class, in your case FoodFatRecyclerViewAdapter and add the following

```
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.foodFatRecView);
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
FoodFatRecyclerViewAdapter foodFatAdapter = new FoodFatRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, sqlResultArray);
rv.setAdapter(foodFatAdapter);
```

Now as for the adding of the result to the textview create a new class called FoodFatRecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class FoodFatRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodFatViewHolder> {

ArrayList<String> mFoodFatItems;
Context mContext;

public FoodFatRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> array) {
    mContext = context;
    mFoodFatItems = array;
}

@Override
public FoodFatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.this_xml_layout_will_describe_the_arrangement_of_the_indi_item_in_the_list_not_the_master_view, parent, false);
    FoodFatViewHolder recyclerView = new FoodFatViewHolder(view);
    return recyclerView;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FoodFatViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.mFatTotalTextView.setText(mFoodFatItems.get(position));
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mFoodFatItems.size();
}
}
```

Now the final piece to the puzzle, the View Holder so create a class called FoodFatViewHolder

```
public class FoodFatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

TextView mFatTotalTextView;

public FoodFatViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    mFatTotalTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.the_textview_id_within_the_individ_item_in_rv_xml_layout);
}
}
```

Voila! It should work

Comment: Thank you very much on your advices. I am sure it will be helpfull for my future progress.

Comment: Let me know if you have any other questions. Also, can you give an upvote if you think it solved your problem? Thanks

Comment: I was on break so I am testing your example now. I should mentioned before that I already made RecyclerView and populated it with all items with special attributes. 
RecyclerView is just for showing info and some popup dialogs.
So I need to display my result `multiplayFat()` in one TextView. I tried to do that with simple `textView = (TextView) mDatabase.multiplayFat();` but it didn't work.

Comment: You first need to declare the xml object and then use '.setText()' on it to show information through it e.g. **Textview text_view_name = (Textview) findViewById(R.id.xml_id_for_tv);** Then you do underneath **DBClass mDb = DBClass.getInstance(MainActivity.this);** Then below this (since you want a single textview and have an array being returned by the function) **Arraylist temp = mDb.multiplyfat();** (do your additions or multiplications and consolidate into a single variable) After you sort that out you have a single value **text_view_name.setText(value);**.

Comment: I tried with this:
`TextView showTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTotalValue);
        List<Food> multiplyValue = mDatabase.multiplyFat();
        showTotal.setText(String.valueOf(multiplyValue));`
I had to use `String.valueOf()` because with out that method `setText()` couldn't be resolved. And the solution was to cast `CharSequence` parameter, but that is not the answer at the end. 
With `String.valueOf()` method in TextView I literally got string like `packageName.Food@42093708`

Comment: The issue you are having is that you are returned a list of items. You can not assign a list to a textview, that is the reason we have listviews and recycle review. **However**, you can loop through these and do something like in the following comment.

Comment: **String temp = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < multiplyValue.size(); i ++) {
           if(i < (multiplyValue.size() - 1)){ 
                temp += multiplyValue.get(i) + ", ";
            } else {
                temp += multiplyValue.get(i);
         }
     }** Now you have the temp variable from which you can write showTotal.setText(temp);  If you just wanted the first value write showTotal.setText(multiplyValue.get(0));

Comment: I added your loop but still I get the same result in TextView (package name instead value). 
Right now debbuger said that there is one item in `multiplyValue` and the loop ends well. But after loop, inside `temp` is saved package name. 
Any idea what is wrong here, because I am really stuck right now.

Comment: LOL. I am sorry, you should be getting that error. What is happening is that you are printing the reference to the Food object. Remember we are retrieving a list of Food objects. To get the value within this object, say there is a **getFoodFat()** function in that class, this is what you want to call **multiplyValue.get(i).getFoodFat();** So adjust my loop to add the function **after each get(i);**

Comment: **Public class Food
    {
    String mFoodFat;
        
    public Food(String foodFat) {
        mFoodFat = foodFat;
    }
        
    public String mFoodFat(){
        return mFoodFat;
    }
        
}**  <- That should be your Food Class. You have just not been asking the class for the value within itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the multiplication total then you shouldn't do a select on COLUMN_FAT_TOTAL. Instead you should do the computation in your select query and store that computation in an alias. You can then use that alias as a result.

Modify your query as below

```
String totalFat = "SELECT " +FoodEntry.COLUMN_FAT_TOTAL + " * " + FoodEntry.COLUMN_GRAM + "AS Result FROM " + FoodEntry.TABLE_NAME";
```

Comment: Great, it really makes more sense. 
So, if I want to show that statement in my TextView I guess I need to call .setText() and call multiplyFat() function ?

Comment: yep that will do.

Comment: @odin_allfather any reason for not accepting my answer :)

Comment: That is the problem when you can not accept more answers. Both you and @Siddharth Garg helped me.

Comment: Sure no problem. Just wanted to check if I missed something

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.  Do the math in the database if it is easy and straight forward, which this example is.

Might I suggest the following (similar to kapsym answer) for your sql statement:

```
 String totalFat = "SELECT " + FoodEntry.COLUMN_FAT_TOTAL + ", " + FoodEntry.COLUMN_GRAM + "," FoodEntry.COLUMN_FAT_TOTAL + " * " + FoodEntry.COLUMN_GRAM + "AS TotalFat FROM " + FoodEntry.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ( " + FoodEntry.COLUMN_FAT_TOTAL + " * " + FoodEntry.COLUMN_GRAM + " ) > 0";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should study the basics of MySQL : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm
After the SELECT, you add column names that you want to retrieve and not expressions.

For your case, Use this Query to get all fat_total & gram entries :

```
String totalFat =         "SELECT " + FoodEntry.COLUMN_FAT_TOTAL + "," + FoodEntry.COLUMN_GRAM + " FROM " + FoodEntry.TABLE_NAME;
```

Then you retrieve fatTotal * gram for each cursor, multiply it and feed it into your storeTotalFat array based on (!= 0) condition.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(totalFat, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do {
        double fat = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(0));
        double gram= Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(1));
        if (fat * gram != 0)
            storeTotalFat.add(new Food(fat * gram));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: `You should study the basics of MySQL` Not really. You meant `You should study the basics of SQL` **SQL**, or Structured Query Language the father of all modern RDBMS, including MySQL.

Comment: I don't think this would be necessary. This would mean getting additional columns of data from DB and then doing an additional set of operation outside. This can be easily achieved from a single query if all that is needed is the multiplication